# Why does my program terminate after the first frame of the video?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working on a program which takes the video from a webcam as input and then detects movement within this video, drawing lines around objects to show where they've moved to and from.

However, when I run this program, all it does it display one still image from my webcam. I have a pretty good idea why this is happening - the if-statement `if (!(matFrame.empty()))` is being evaluated as false, so the `else` statement runs, changing `keepProcessing` to `false`. This then terminates the while-loop, leaving nothing but `ims.showImage(matFrame);` as an output.

I can't find why this might be happening though, so I was hoping someone here might be able to help me. I've posted the code below so you can check for problems. I've also tried running it with a video to make sure this wasn't the fault of my webcam, and I found the same problem. Thanks for your time.

```
public class CaptureVideo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // load the Core OpenCV library by name

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    // create video capture device object

    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

    // try to use the hardware device if present

    int CAM_TO_USE = 0;

    // create a new image object

    Mat matFrame = new Mat();

    Mat previousFrame = new Mat();

    Mat diffFrame = new Mat();

    // try to open first capture device (0)

    try {
        cap.open(CAM_TO_USE);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("No webcam attached");

        // otherwise try opening a video file 

        try{
            cap.open("files/video.mp4");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("No video file found");
        }
    }

    // if the a video capture source is now open

    if (cap.isOpened())
    {

        // create a new window object

        Imshow ims = new Imshow("From video source ... ");

        boolean keepProcessing = true;

           // add a flag to check whether the first frame has been read
           boolean firstFrame = true;

           while (keepProcessing)
            {   
                // save previous frame before getting next one, but
                // only do this if the first frame has passed
                if (!firstFrame)
                    previousFrame = matFrame.clone();

                // grab the next frame from video source
                cap.grab();

                // decode and return the grabbed video frame
                cap.retrieve(matFrame);

                // if the frame is valid (not end of video for example)
                if (!(matFrame.empty()))
                {

                    // if we are on the first frame, only show that and
                    // set the flag to false
                    if (firstFrame) {
                        ims.showImage(matFrame);
                        firstFrame = false;
                    }

                    // now show absolute difference after first frame
                    else {                
                        Core.absdiff(matFrame, previousFrame, diffFrame);
                        ims.showImage(diffFrame);                 
                    }

                    // now convert it to grey and threshold it

                    Mat grey = new Mat();
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(diffFrame, grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

                    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(grey, diffFrame, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
                                                Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 10);

                    // now clean it up using some morphological operations

                    Size ksize = new Size(15,15);
                    Mat kernel =  Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, ksize);

                    Imgproc.morphologyEx(diffFrame, diffFrame, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);

                    // find the all the contours from the binary image using the edge to contour
                    // stuff we looked at in lectures

                    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new Vector<MatOfPoint>();

                    Imgproc.findContours(diffFrame, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                    // draw the contours on image 2 in red

                    Imgproc.drawContours(matFrame, contours, -1, new Scalar(0,0,255));

                    // find the largest contour by area 

                    double maxArea = 0;
                    int maxAreaIndex = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {

                        double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i), false);

                        if ( area > maxArea )
                        {
                            maxArea = area;
                            maxAreaIndex = i;
                        }
                    }

                    // draw the largest contour in red

                    Imgproc.drawContours(matFrame, contours, maxAreaIndex, new Scalar(0,255,0));

                    // create a new window objects

                    Imshow ims_diff = new Imshow("Difference");

                   // display images

                    ims_diff.showImage(diffFrame);

                    // display image with a delay of 40ms (i.e. 1000 ms / 25 = 25 fps)                
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } else { 
                    keepProcessing = false;

                }
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be seeing an exception on your console or output window:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3739
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:4598)
    at CaptureVideo.main(CaptureVideo.java:87)
```

Which references line 87 (in my source file) which is:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(diffFrame, grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

The problem is that `diffFrame` hasn't been initialized so it's bombing out. I was able to get it to work locally by adding this block:

```
// decode and return the grabbed video frame
cap.retrieve(matFrame);

// *** START
if (firstFrame) {
    firstFrame = false;
    continue;
}
// *** End

// if the frame is valid (not end of video for example)
if (!(matFrame.empty()))
```

The effect of this is that the first frame will not be painted, but subsequent ones will.  Also, code later on will open a new `JFrame` (`Imshow`) for every "diff" frame, which will quickly kill your machine, so be ready to kill the process.

Comment: Also, the `Imshow` class I found on GitHub is not what I would call stellar code, so the performance really sucks.  Not sure if you are using the same one or not, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks. Would turning `diffFrame` into a local variable and adding it under `boolean firstName = true;` also be another way of doing this though?

Comment: I don't see how that would change anything, no.  But if it works for you, great.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Sorry it's taken a while to reply. My actual laptop seems to be throwing all kinds of errors for perfectly good code, so I need to get to a university computer. I tried playing around with the local variable idea, but nothing worked. I've since run your code, and it works, but I can't find the bit which is causing JFrames to proliferate. Do you know how I can change this so that it simply updates the one, current JFrame?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I've got it. Didn't realise the creation of the JFrame was within the `while` loop...